# Book for WebService SOAP and WSDL in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have searched for WebServices which utilizes SOAP and WSDL, wasn't lucky enough to find any. Even those tutorial that I found and testing works well when both server and client deployed in same web server.

Also I need to understand the jargon's of WebService completely.

So please recommend some good books.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523643/book-recommendations-for-java-webservices

Comment: Any book about jax-ws should give you a good basic understanding of SOAP and WSDL's

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon Thanks for pointing out. I will check that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Oreilly Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0 book is the best one I have used. It was given to me during a training class and it covers all of the topics you mention.

Comment: Thanks. I will download this book.